# Best practices: efficient sprite drawing in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, 2d, sprite

What is an efficient way to draw sprites in my 2D XNA game? To be more concrete, I have split this question up into 4 questions.

---

I used to declare Game1's spriteBatch **static**, and called `SpriteBatch.Begin` and `.Close` in every `IDrawable.Draw`. That didn't work well. Giving each drawable it's own SpriteBatch also didn't work well.

**Q1**: I assume it's best to have **one** SpriteBatch instance, and only call begin/close **once**. Is this correct?

---

Currently, my `Game1.Draw` looks something like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();

base.Draw(gameTime); // draws elements of Game.Components

// ...

spriteBatch.End();
```

**Q2**: This way, `Begin` is called only once. Is this the way to go? How did you guys solve this?

---

**Q3**: Also, every component has it's own `IGameComponent.LoadContent` method. Am I supposed to load my content there? Or is it better to load content at a parent class, such as `Game1.LoadContent`?

---

I realise that I should never load the same content twice, so I have given my drawable components both a static and a non-static `Texture2D`, and gave them 2 constructors:

```
static Texture2D defaultTexture;
public Texture2D MyTexture;

public Enemy()
    : this(defaultTexture) { }

public Enemy(Texture2D texture)
{
    MyTexture = texture;
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    if (MyTexture == null)
    {
        if (defaultTexture == null)
        {
            defaultTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("enemy");
        }

        MyTexture = defaultTexture;
    }
}
```

This way, the default textures of a class are only loaded the first time `LoadContent` is called on that class. However, when the parameter `texture` is specified in the constructor, I'll have to load that texture beforehand.

**Q4**: I think there should be better ways to do this. I'm thinking of creating a texture dictionary with their asset names as string. What would you suggest?

Comment: I do it in the same way. If i have not reason to use multiply sprite batch (eg. for split-screen, different effect, and so), i'm calling begin and end only once in main class of game, and draw everything between this begin and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used to declare Game1's spriteBatch static

You don't have to have it static. Just make a singleton. Inside `Draw` method

```
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = ScreenManager.SpriteBatch; // singletion SpriteBatch
spriteBatch.Begin();
// Draw the background
spriteBatch.Draw(background, ...
foreach (var enemy in enemys)
{
     enemy.Draw(gameTime);
}
// etc.
spriteBatch.End(); // call here end 
base.Draw(gameTime); // and then call the base class
```

> I assume it's best to have one SpriteBatch instance, and only call
>   begin/close once. Is this correct?

I advice you to open and end the `SpriteBatch` within one method. It will help you avoid conflicts with `SpriteBatch` that started drawing, but didn't finish.

Are you adding your elements to the global collection of components? This is a bad idea to add drawable to this collection. You cannot control the order of drawing, the components are global. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421275/is-it-drawablegamecomponent-the-wrong-tool-for-creating-buttons).

Implement in your components IUpdatable and IDrawable and call them in your code where you need it. Get rid of the static stuff and use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) istead.

> Also, every component has it's own IGameComponent.LoadContent method. Am I supposed to load my content there? Or is it better to load content at a parent class, such as Game1.LoadContent?

You should load assets when you need it and you are responsible for it. You don'y have to load all 30 levels when user just started the game, do you? For example, when your game starts you load all assets that you need for your start screen and main menu. If you load just what you need the player is happy that game starts fast. Then player wants to start the gameplay. Here you can load the assets on a separate thread to keep the app responsive.

> I think there should be better ways to do this. I'm thinking of creating a texture dictionary with their asset names as string. What would you suggest?

`Content.Load` is cached already, so you don't have to do it.

Comment: You seem to call `Draw` on enemy manually. In my game, I have added all drawables (such as walls, and enemies) to `Game1.Components` list, so `Draw` is called when calling the base class.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `Content.Load` handles redundant calls itself. However, is it *that* bad to use the global collection? I don't have to control drawing order.

Comment: Also, I understand that I should not load all levels. But, for example, should I load `bullet.png` when the player shoots, and unload it when it's gone? Or should I load the image at the start of the level?

Comment: By default you shouldn't care about unloading. `Content` will manage the caching. GameComponents is a design flaw. See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-are-the-cons-of-using-drawablegamecomponent-for-every-instance-of-a-game-ob/9209#9209

Comment: But then again, should I load required sprites at level init, or when they first occur? :)

Comment: That depends. If you have a file `player.png` that is small you can load it and user won't notice that. If you have a lot of files to load than you can make a loading screen that will load it before the init of the level. That also depends on the hardware. Is it phone or PC?

Comment: PC. It seems I have no further questions, thanks for answering them all. :)

Answer (score 1):

as far as can be gleaned from [tutorials](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/SpriteBatch.Draw.php) [around](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/spritebatch-basics)

calling begin and end only once is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

**Q4**: I think there should be better ways to do this. I'm thinking of creating a texture dictionary with their asset names as string. What would you suggest?

---

**A4**: I usually create a `Dictionary<string, Texture2D> NameTextureDic` within my `TextureLib` class (which handles loading png images at runtime), so I can get any texture like so:

```
var t2d = textureLib.NameTextureDic["tree-4"];
```